# Somar valores vindo do select/option e jogar resultado no input em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Alguém pode me ajudar? quero somar os valores vindo desses dois options e jogar no input "Resultado" em javascript

```html
<select id="select01">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id="select02">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="Resultado">
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá **ruandevjr** uma maneira de resolver o problema poderá ser assim

```js
const select1 = document.getElementById('select01')
const select2 = document.getElementById('select02')
const input = document.getElementById('Resultado')

const ChangeInput = () => {
    const res = Number(select1.value) + Number(select2.value)
    input.value = res
}
// Quando a página for atualizada o input não ficar vazio
const res = Number(select1.value) + Number(select2.value)
input.value = res

select1.onchange = ChangeInput
select2.onchange = ChangeInput
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Todas as suas configurações de head -->
  <script defer src='./file.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- O seu código HTML -->
  <select id="select01">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    
    <select id="select02">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    
    <input type="text" id="Resultado">
</body>
</html>
```

**Espero ter ajudado**

Comment: Ajudou sim!! Muito obrigado

Comment: Esse código nao ajuda a pegar o valor se entre 0 a 4 dos options alterar para por exemplo 13 qualquer um dele o calculo nao é feito ate mesmo o value se alterar para 01 02 tbm não ajuda... ou seja o js ta ali mas não se aplica a real intenção.